# Is this reaction realistic enough?

Tags: internal-consistency, technology, geology

I'm building a world which has, apart from the 'usual' stuff, 2 types of stones (haven't really decided on a name yet).

1. Stone A holds some form of energy but when prompted by Stone B it will release its energy in some form of light. To charge this stone, one can either put it in direct sunlight or have it absorb enough of Stone B to charge it up to a certain threshold. So this stone is rechargable to give light more then just 1 time.
2. Stone B also holds energy. But rather then light it will give of some other kind of radiation (or anything undetectable by human eyes). This stone functions as a catalyst to trigger the reaction in Stone A to illuminate. This stone might be depletable. Favorably the radiation given could be used for other purposes then just trigger the reaction in Stone A.

When I was figuring this out I did a lot of handwavingand and would like to reduce this to a minimum (but there might still be involved).

In my world I would like to give these stones all kinds of appliances.
Maybe as a flashlight or a weapon or a microwave or a streetlight, maybe things I haven't thought of yet.

Long exposure to any stone in relative small doses should be non-lethal to humans. Though if usage might cause harm that is just fine.

What I am looking for is a way to describe the relationship and reaction between the 2 types of stone. Preferably also the reasons why it would work as I described (in the appliances I would like to use them for). And perhaps it already exists in the real world somehow?

---

**EDIT:**

The details provided are not fixed yet. So if you feel like something feels off feel free to interpret them to make more sense. But the less you need to change the better. Details provided how these stones would work in the example appliances would be highly valued.

Comment: [Phosphorecence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescence)?

Comment: Also look at any fluorescent lamp, there are a powder used in it to absorve the non visible light the ionized gases emits and re-emit it as visible light

Comment: @jean oh! Phosphorecence does seem exactly the term i was looking for in Stone A, like glow-in-the-dark stuff. What would Stone B need to emit to charge Stone A to have this effect occur?

Comment: It's weird to me that Stone B is used both to release energy from Stone A and to put energy back into Stone A. Do you have more details on how the "absorb enough of Stone B" happens without also being "prompted by Stone B"?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Stone B is used to emit some kind of radiation or stuff to charge Stone A. I would've loved to have Stone B be some kind of catalyst to either improve or start an immidiate reaction in Stone A as well if possible. Feel free to adjust and point out anything that does not make sense to something that is more likely.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus So something like, being *near* Stone B will charge Stone A, but if Stone B *touches* stone A then the energy is released? That sounds fairly difficult unless the substance called "Stone B" is actually two materials (e.g. a radioactive core with a catalyst outer layer) and it just happens to form in the right configuration to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If stone A is an electrical conductor, and stone B is a magnet, you can use your duo to create electricity.  Moving the magnet (and associated field) past the conductor will induce an electrical current within the conductor.  The electricity can be used to light a light or do other work.,

https://makezine.com/projects/make-41-tinkering-toys/induction-instruction/

[image: electrical induction]

This is how electrical generators work in real life.  In real life you have to keep the magnetic field moving, which means moving the magnet.

For your world: imagine stone B is a substance in which the constituent subatomic particles can be spun up so the magnetic field rotates without the magnetic stone itself rotating.  You could hold it still in your hand and its field would spin around it.  You would not notice this.  But if you held stone B near the conductor stone A, the induced current in stone A would drain the spin energy from stone B until the magnetic field stopped moving, at which point no more current would be induced.

The magnetic field is your invisible radiation.  The spin energy is the deplorable aspect.  Alternate use: Stone B could also ring a bell very fast if held next to a magnetic ringer, which would be alternately repelled and attracted by the spinning magnet.  If the spin was really fast it would be more of a buzzer than a bell.

You can attribute the spinning magnetic field effect principle to something involving proton spin, which invokes dense particle physics incomprehensible to most.  The few who do understand will have a good laugh.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_spin_crisis

Comment: Oef it is a hard concept but it sounds cool. But if i understand correctly this proton spin will make my Stone B have a spinning magnetic field that can charge Stpne A. Does this combine with phosphorecence?

Comment: The field does not charge stone A.  It induced electrical current within stone A.  You could have stone A glow if it conducts electric current, like an LED.  Or you could use it to power a device like a regular flashlight.

Comment: @willik maybe charge is the wrong word for what i meant. I was to understand that a photon was the quantum of both light AND electromagnetic energy which is how i thought the proton spin would cause the luminesce effect in Stone A to happen.

Comment: Well (waving hands) if you attribute the spinning magnetic spin to proton spin, that would be a property of stone B.  Stone A would produce electrical current - it could just be a lump of copper and it would produce current.  You could have stone A something which both produced electric current and glowed - some LED-like property might work.

Comment: I will probably wave my hands a bit more. But seems like this is combination does the trick for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is realistic.

Something similar exists, and it is actually used to measure the age of certain stones: it is called [thermoluminesce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoluminescence).

> High energy radiation creates electronic excited states in crystalline materials. In some materials, these states are trapped, or arrested, for extended periods of time by localized defects, or imperfections, in the lattice interrupting the normal intermolecular or inter-atomic interactions in the crystal lattice. Quantum-mechanically, these states are stationary states which have no formal time dependence; however, they are not stable energetically. Heating the material enables the trapped states to interact with phonons, i.e. lattice vibrations, to rapidly decay into lower-energy states, causing the emission of photons in the process.
>
> Thermoluminescence is a common geochronology tool for dating pottery or other fired archeological materials, as heat empties or resets the thermoluminescent signature of the material

Stone A in this case would be the pottery, while stone B would be a naturally radioactive stone.

You need only to add heat to release the luminescence.

Comment: This does mean I need another outside source to power the process (heat in this case). This would make some of my appliances really hard to accomplish. Or do you have some idea for that as well?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus, it depends on how much handwavium you are willing to use. The mechanism per se is perfectly plausible, and as heat source you can use an electric resistance, maybe...

Comment: I am in no way completely commited to a purely realistic reaction. But I am exploring how far I can go with just these materials. Your insight is helpful so far though :)